# How to open a specific excel file with a batch script and command line arguments?

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file

I designed an excel spreadsheet that takes data from a server using an RTD feed and processes it. I want the excel file to open automatically during the computers startup. The way that I have decided to go about doing this is to write a batch script that opens the excel file and to then put that batch script in the computers startup folder.

The problem I am running into relates to the batch script. The RTD feed does not work if I use the default shortcut for excel. Instead I have to use a shortcut that has the following target line:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /a "CompanyExcelAddin.CompanyFunctions"
```

I am able to open the file using this command line

```
start `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\...\filename.xlsm"`
```

but I am not able to open a file using the following bash command

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /a "CompanyExcelAddin.CompanyFunctions" "C:\...\filename.xlsm"
```

If I open it using the first batch script the RTD feed doesn't work. If I try to run the second script the batch script doesn't run.

How do I write a batch script that takes command line arguments for the startup program?

Comment: Batch scripts and bash scripts are different animals, powershell even moreso. Please edit your 'question' by removing the non necessary tags and changing what is a broad/generic question to something more specific. As you currently have it, it looks like you are requesting a free solution using any method which is both rude and technically off topic.

Comment: Put an empty pair of quotes before any path components, like `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\...\EXCEL.EXE" /a ...`, because `start` often interprets the first quoted string as a window title...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@echo off
set params=%*
start excel "MyWorkbook.xlsm" /e/%params%
```

Let's suppose you named it "MyBatch.bat", then you call it like this:

```
MyBatch.bat Hello/World1
```

Use space " " to separate parameters.
Use slash "/" instead of space for parameters with spaces.

In case you do not like the string I believe you can also do this (in a *.bat file): 
`start excel "MyWorkbook.xlsm" /e/%param1%/%param2%/%param3%.....`

In case you need to open several Excel instances:

```
@echo off
set params=%*
for %%C in (%params%) do (
    start excel "MyWorkbook.xlsm" /e/%%C
)
```

Comment: How can I open a protected sheet/workbook from this same batch script ? Is it just a matter of passing another parameter or a whole different story ?

Comment: [Excel VBA - Automatically Input Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326986/excel-vba-automatically-input-password)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend using a scheduled task over the startup folder (consistent behavior).  Trigger on login, or however you need it, and execute `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File 'thing.ps1'`.  It looks like you may be passing the arguments out of order for the Excel exe.

```
$EXE = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
& $EXE 'C:\...\filename.xlsm' /a 'CompanyExcelAddin.CompanyFunctions'
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what RTD is ? can yu  please define acronyms at least once for everyones sake. We are not in the British Military, or a Monty Python skit.
Easiest way from command prompt (CMD);
start excel
or
start excel W:\mortgages\myfile.xls

Picaso not Pollock

You can also use a BATCH file with these commands, which also works best for TASK SCHEDULER, but I would always put net use command for the drive on a network since the TASK SCHED instance may not recognize them.  Task scheduler is really problematic with black box responses (in code), but I have found using a batch file resolves most issues.